# Alchemist meets time-traveller

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I would like to identify a short story, probably written before 1975, in which an alchemist somehow captures a time-traveller and demands a quantity of gold in return for his release.

Comment: I vaguely recall something from _Omni_ like this...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Exchange, David. See [our great guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help coming up with details that are unique and useful for story identification.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm thinking Murray Leinster.